# SQLAlchemy: Column Type Inferred From Foreign Key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I defined a many-to-many association table...

```py
derived_prime_sport_stats = Table(
    'derived_prime_sport_stats',
    Base.metadata,
    Column(
        'prime_sport_id',
        ForeignKey('prime_sports.id', ondelete='RESTRICT'),
        primary_key=True
    ),
    Column(
        'stat_record_id',
        ForeignKey('stat_record.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
        primary_key=True
    )
)
```

...ran a migration and moved on.

Later, realising that I'd forgotten to pass the `type_` parameter to the constructor of each of the columns in the `Table` I assumed that the the migration must have failed.

However, `mysql> show create table derived_prime_sport_stats;` shows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `derived_prime_sport_stats` (
  `prime_sport_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `stat_record_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`prime_sport_id`,`stat_record_id`),
  KEY `fk_derived_prime_sport_stats_stat_record_id_stat_record` (`stat_record_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_derived_prime_sport_stats_prime_sport_id_prime_sports` FOREIGN KEY (`prime_sport_id`) REFERENCES `prime_sports` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_derived_prime_sport_stats_stat_record_id_stat_record` FOREIGN KEY (`stat_record_id`) REFERENCES `stat_record` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

...the types have been configured in accordance with the type of the related column without being explicitly specified.

This behavior is documented but I was unable to find a related question on stackoverflow, so I'm putting this here as a reference as I think that many who interact with SQLAlchemy mostly through the ORM, may not be aware of the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for the `type_` arg to `Column`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.__init__) specifies:

> If the type is None or is omitted, it will first default to the
>   special type NullType. If and when this Column is made to refer to
>   another column using ForeignKey and/or ForeignKeyConstraint, the type
>   of the remote-referenced column will be copied to this column as well,
>   at the moment that the foreign key is resolved against that remote
>   Column object.

When the `ForeignKey`'s parent column is attached to it's table, the [`ForeignKey._set_table()`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/64865304051b2af1ee4f90c6bf5e93378d4f302c/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py#L2070) method is called and in that method, the FK resolves the column of the foreign table that it references. At that point, if the FK's parent column has no type, it sets it from the foreign column. That happens [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/64865304051b2af1ee4f90c6bf5e93378d4f302c/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py#L1983) in `ForeignKey._set_target_column()`:

```py
# propagate TypeEngine to parent if it didn't have one
if self.parent.type._isnull:
    self.parent.type = column.type
```

Interestingly, in the very first example of defining tables in [the expression language tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html):

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey
>>> metadata = MetaData()
>>> users = Table('users', metadata,
...     Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
...     Column('name', String),
...     Column('fullname', String),
... )

>>> addresses = Table('addresses', metadata,
...   Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
...   Column('user_id', None, ForeignKey('users.id')),
...   Column('email_address', String, nullable=False)
...  )
```

...the `addresses.user_id` column has it's type explicitly set to `None` to leverage this feature, however there doesn't appear to be any explanation of that until the API reference for `Column`.